# how can I import django to my python path

Tags: python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code, terminal

I started my project, it was running successfully until I returned back to continue, and encountered this problem. I typed 'python manage.py makemigrations' and this error message popped up on terminal
'ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?'
How can I resolve this problem

Comment: do you have virtual environment?

Comment: Yes please, I do have

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you activate your virtual environment?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `Django`, this error is giving because django is not installed

```
$ python -m pip install Django
```

Comment: Im using pipenv by the way, I install django and still was encountering the same issues

Comment: You may have not installed django inside the pipenv eg:      `$ mkdir folder && cd folder`
`$ pipenv install django~=3.1.0`
`$ pipenv shell`
`(folder) $ django-admin.py startproject my_project .`
`(folder) $ python manage.py migrate`
`(folder) $ python manage.py runserver`

Comment: This worked inside the virutal env.